# howto add database to swing desktop application

Tags: java, database, swing, netbeans, jt400

I have created an desktop application in Netbeans 7.0 and i have the files, app, view and aboutbox.

And i want to add an database object that is accessible in the application in the duration of the applications lifetime, that closes when the app closes.

I am using the JT400 library to connect to an A/S 400 system for the database queries, so i cant use the database desktop application route. (or if I can, enlighten me)

I would like to have a database object that i can access throughout the entire project and fill my GUI/lists/comboboxes with this connection, and then use it also during the application usage when the customer makes queries to the database.

But I cant seem to find a good tutorial on how to do this. Anyone have ideas, and im pretty fresh with the swing framework as well.

I tried first to make an Java application and add the elements myself, but the layout part took too much time so i want to have the ability to layout the application through Netbeans.

Comment: The JT400 library allows accessing your database in Java. Just use it. If you dream about being able to just point and click to build your application, then forget it. Learn Swing, learn the JT400 library, and start programming in Java to use the JT400 library to populate your Swing component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a tutorial on [how to build a Java desktop application that talks to a database in NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-db.html). Spend some time going through the tutorial and check out the code. Run the code in debug mode to have a sense how does it execute and it's going to be much easier to build such an app.

Answer (score 2):

How about mapping DB Table to java entity Classes using [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) ?